# I want to read json file

Tags: dataset, chatbot

I tried to read json file, but I keep getting an error.

This is my dataset:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "pagi",
      "patterns": [ "pagi", "Halo", "good morning" ],
      "responses": [ "pagi kak ada yang bisa dibantu?", "selamat pagi juga kak", "Hi!", "Good morning!"],
      "context": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And I got this error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 8 column 2 (char 237)

Comment: The JSON shown appears to be valid.  What language are you using and how are you using this JSON data?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the error?